# Entity Framework Code-First One-To-One Relationship

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have two database tables:

**Customers**

- CustomerId (PK)
- Name
- ...

**CustomerSettings**

- CustomerId (PK)
- Setting1
- Setting2
- ...

Is it possible to have these classes using code-first? If so, what is the fluent mapping?

```
public class Customer
{
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public int Name { get; set; }
    public CustomerSetting CustomerSetting { get; set; }
}

public class CustomerSetting
{
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public int Setting1 { get; set; }
    public int Setting2 { get; set; }
    public Customer Customer { get; set; }
}
```

I personally don't like one-to-one tables. After all, why not just add the setting columns to the customer table? Unfortunately, this is what I need to develop against. I can't figure the correct code-first mappings for such a scenario. Thanks for your help.

Comment: One possible scenario to use PK with FK to anoter PK is inhertience. Though of coruse this isn't your case.  I've suggested the solution in my answer.

Comment: It sounds like someone else is dictating the data model.  In that case, Model first or Db first is a better choice than code first.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going for code first and want to have both Customer And CustomerSettings classes,
but only a single table for both, as your post suggests , 
I would use complex types. 
see a good example here:

http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2010/12/11/entity-association-mapping-with-code-first-part-1-one-to-one-associations.aspx

So , your object model should look like this (I've not tested it):

```
public class Customer
{
    public Customer()
    {
        CustomerSetting= new CustomerSetting();
    }

    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public int Name { get; set; }
    public CustomerSetting CustomerSetting { get; set; }
}

[ComplexType]
public class CustomerSetting
{
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public int Setting1 { get; set; }
    public int Setting2 { get; set; }
    public Customer Customer { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, my post suggests needing two tables. My aside states that I wouldn't have designed my database using two tables, but unfortunately I'm not at liberty to change the existing two table structure.

Comment: In that case, I agree with @Maess , if you already have the database, model first is the way to go , not code first.

Answer (score 0):

Your model classess are correct, if you want you can add this to your model builder to specify which table is the "main one":

```
.Entity<Customer>()
.HasOptional(c => c.CustomerSetting)
.WithRequired(u => u.Customer);
```